# Convert Input given as n**x to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a Python function which converts a screen/console input as for example 10**8 to the integer 100000000.  This would save typing all those zeros with the possibility of error.

Comment: `eval("10**8")`?

Comment: Use scientific notation, e.g. `s = '1e8'`, and then evaluate it as `int(float(s))` (but it only works for n=10, and for x up to 22).

Comment: @Frank Better use `ast.literal_eval` for evaluating user-input.

Comment: @tobias_k fails for this input though (by itself)

Comment: Underscores can help readability: `int('100_000_000')`.

Comment: IMO the proper answer is to write a parser https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/6260170

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you so much I didn't know `ast.literal_eval` before. However I tried it and as @Chris_Rands said it didn't work. I checked the docs and it only works with `strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.` https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @tobias_k: As Frank already pointed out, `ast_literal()` won't work for this—but the more relevant line in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is "It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing."

Answer (score 3):

these are two possible solutions:

```
inp = "10**8"

a = eval(inp) #don't use eval for untrusted input
b = int(inp.split("**")[0])**int(inp.split("**")[1])

print (10**8 == a == b)
```

output:

> True

Comment: Or `pow(*map(int, inp.split("**")))`

Comment: Liam - perfect, thanks.  a is simplest for my purposes.